# Method level access control in Spring using XML configuration

Tags: xml, spring, authorization, acl

We can implement method level access control using the following code:

```
public class HelloController implements IHelloController{

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
    public String welcome(ModelMap model){

       model.addAttribute("message","Welcome Admin");
       return "hello";
    }
}
```

I would like to know, is it possible to restrict the access to particular method by some XML configuration.If yes, then how?

hail SO!!

Comment: why don't you like annotations?

Comment: I don't have any problem with annotations. But in big projects, annotations will make you compile your code again and again, for the slightest change. In short, it is little time consuming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pointcut expressions` inside your `<global-method-security>` tag in your XML configuration.
This will also let you match multiple methods with a regex, if you need to.

Example:

```
<global-method-security>
    <protect-pointcut expression="execution(* com.yourpackage.IHelloController.welcome(..))" access="ROLE_ADMIN"/>
</global-method-security>
```

Read more [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/reference/htmlsingle/#ns-global-method).